# How can I get all the extensions in a directory?

Tags: vb.net

How can I get all the extensions in a directory?

This is for a VB.NET Windows application.

Thanks,
Babu Kumarasamy.

Answer (score 3):

Get all files in the directory, get the extensions from them, and remove duplicates:

```
Dim extensions As String() = _
  Directory.GetFiles(path) _
  .Select(Function(f As String) Path.GetExtension(f)) _
  .Distinct() _
  .ToArray()
```

Edit:
Changed to VB syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through all the files in  a directory and take the extension of each file.  Check if it doesn't already exist in your list and if not add it.  by the time you go through all the files you will have your list.

There isn't a single method to do this.

Comment: actually if you use a Set instead of a List you don't have to write any deduplication logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a LINQ query with the VB.NET *Group By Into* syntax:

```
Dim extensions = From file In New DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles() _
                 Group file By file.Extension Into Group
```

You can then iterate through them like so:

```
For Each extension In extensions
    Console.WriteLine(extension.Extension)
Next
```